# How to Update UI slider in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a top down shooter in unity, In the game the players health is represented by a UI slider.While moving between scenes I save the health value of the player using the down given code, and use GetFloat to set in next level.The problem i am facing is that when the players is spawned in the next level the UI slider moves to 0 instead of the saved value until some health damage is done to the player after which it is set to the saved value.

**Saving Player health**

```
public void yesTeleport(string levelname)       
{
    healthNumber = healthSlider.value;
    SceneManager.LoadScene (levelname);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HealthValue", healthNumber);
    PlayerPrefs.Save ();
}
```

**Setting Player health in next level**

```
public Slider healthSlider;

void Start () {

    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    healthSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HealthValue");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

**1**.You are saving with `SetFloat` and loading with `GetInt`. You should be saving and loading with `SetFloat` and `GetFloat`.

**2**.You are loading new scene before saving the `healthNumber` value. It should be the other way around. The `SceneManager.LoadScene (levelname);` code should be put after `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HealthValue", healthNumber);` and  `PlayerPrefs.Save ();`

Your code should look like this:

```
public void yesTeleport(string levelname)       
{
    healthNumber = healthSlider.value;
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HealthValue", healthNumber);
    PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    SceneManager.LoadScene (levelname);
}

public Slider healthSlider;
void Start () {

    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    healthSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HealthValue");
}
```

Also make sure to call the `yesTeleport` function from one of the Unity's callback functions that get's called when scene is unloading. One of them  is the `OnDisable` function...

```
void OnDisable()
{
    yesTeleport (...);
}
```

Please rename the `yesTeleport` function to something that actually make sense. Maybe that function should be named "*saveAndReload*" ?